# Access my xampp server through my public IP address wouldn't work

Tags: apache, networking, xampp, web-hosting, server

Hey Guys I am trying to configure my xampp server so that people outside the LAN can access my website through my public IP address. I know there are many answers out there and I have tried them all but it still wouldn't work. So here is the description:

I am able to access my xampp server through localhost, 127.0.0.1, and 192.168.1.xxx ip addresses but when I type in my public ip address it wouldn't work. (I am a college student and I live in apartments and I am pretty sure that we all in our community have the same public ip address) Any way, I forwarded all the ports by signing into my default gateway.

The strange thing is when I login to my router default gateway(192.168.1.1), under the status tab, I see what is call the Internet IP address for ipv4 which is 10.12.xx.xxx which seems to be unique but is not my public IP Address. So I tried accessing my server through that address and it works. I can also connect to the server by connecting to my roommate's router with the same IP address 10.12.xx.xxx. Then I try to connect it through my mobile which is connected to my wifi, that works too. However, when I switch off the wifi on my phone and get on 3g I can't access my server. So I can only access my server over the LAN(My community). Is there any way I can access it over WAN? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also the ports I have forwarded are 80, 443 (for HTTP Server) and port 21 for FileZilla FTP

Comment: Sorry, could you please edit your question such that it is readable? Thanks.

Comment: IPV4 addresses in the range of `10.x.x.x` are non-routeable addresses. So that certainly _cannot_ be the real "public" ip address. Most likely your gateway is still behind some further gateway. Most likely you have not forwarded your ports through _that_ gateway.

Comment: But even if I don't forward my ports, shouldn't I still be able to connect to my server through my public ip address instead of typing in localhost?

Comment: No, why should you? Your local system does not know about your "public" ip address, so it cannot use a "shortcut" route. It sends the request to the address which does not know what to do with it. I am convinced that you cannot do what you try to do. This would be against all rules in such a local network. Take a look at renting a virtual server at a hosting provider instead. They come for a few cents a month these days.